# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When I try to update a user profile in my app i get the following error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.UserDetails_dbo.Companies_CompanyId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "aspnet-eksp-20161223071733", table "dbo.Companies", column
>   'CompanyId'. The statement has been terminated.

Although it may look self explenatory I have no idea how to solve it and make my code work. I am very new with EF and the whole platform in general.

I do have a foreign key in my model, of course, and this foreing key field is **not** empty, it has a value.

Here is the model :

```
public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserDetailsId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageBase64 => System.Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserCountry { get; set; }
    public string UserPostalCode { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public string identtyUserId { get; set; }

}
```

And the controller method :

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "UserDetailsId,ImageData,FirstName,LastName,UserAddress,UserCountry,UserPostalCode,UserPhoneNumber,CompanyId,identtyUserId")] UserDetails userDetails, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[UploadImage.ContentLength];
                UploadImage.InputStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                userDetails.ImageData = buf;

                db.Entry(userDetails).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            //ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName", userDetails.CompanyId);
            return View(userDetails);
        }
```

In the view I can update everything but the last two fields(in the model), but i doubt this is the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of CompanyId, when you POST your edit? Does this value exists in the corresponding table at your database? It seems like you send an update statement to the database, that contains a value for CompanyId that it doesn't exist at the Companies table.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question i don't update this value. The value for the last two fields from the model is inserted when the user registers and i don't want to change it after.

Comment: @RobertRoss can youtry my answer please . I just omitted all properties just used FirstName but please try to see if exception is gone or not

Comment: It seems that `UserDetails` has a column named `Companies_CompanyId` in the database. Check if it also has a column `CompanyId`. I suspect that the the statement updates `CompanyId`, not `Companies_CompanyId`. You can also check that by monitoring the insert statement and its values. If you see both columns, there's a mapping problem we should try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you tru this  . please replace this code under you if statement .

```
      byte[] buf = new byte[UploadImage.ContentLength];
            UploadImage.InputStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            userDetails.ImageData = buf;
     --- here first read the dataof edited userDetail get it from context and chage this object state to modified and thn save.
            var currentUserDetail =   db.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.UserDetailid= Id);
            currentUserDetail.FirstName= userDetails.userDetails;
            db.Entry(currentUserDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: This is a work-around. Might be useful, but it doesn't address the issue itself. Little nitpick: it's not necessary to set the `Modified` state.

Comment: @GertArnold :Thanks you found it useful . I had same issue I didnot find any solution I am not ninja od EF but what  I understand is that it is related to the State when EF loaded the entities and then you add something to them it treat them a new entry and then try  create insert statement even if it already exist  .I am sure this case is same. if user run  sql server profiler then you will see insert instead of update .

Comment: You add nothing to `currentUserDetail`, you only modifies its properties. The change tracker will notice these changes.

Comment: @GertArnold if I am not wrong you are saying that I dont needto change State to modify ?I need to check it . May be you are right need to give a try :) Thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserDetails_dbo` table has a foreign key column named `Companies_CompanyId`. You are sending an updated record to the database, a `UserDetails_dbo` record but the value of the `Companies_CompanyId` does not exist in the database. Therefore, you are getting that error.

Make sure the updated record you are sending has a value for the foreign key and make sure the value exists in the database.